# How do I programmatically disable IIS6 Applications (not virtual directories)

Tags: c#, vb.net, iis-6

I am looking for a way to pragmatically remove IIS6 applications (via vb or c#).  Through IIS Manager, this would be as simple as navigating to the application I want to disable, right click for properties and clicking remove.  This would leave the file system intact and remove the folder from being an application.  I've seen lots of information on how to remove an entire virtual directory and delete folders, but nothing that I can find explains how to simply disable the application.

Just to add one other complication, these applications are often nested several folders deep rather than within the root website itself. However, I do know their exact physical path.

I've spend most of my day trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've been able to do with this problem is to stop and start an entire web site. If you can move your application into its own web site within IIS, this will do just what you want. Read more here:
http://adamprescott.net/2011/09/26/programmatically-start-stop-iis-web-sites-in-c/

It also might be worth considering simply renaming the root directory to something like  "Foo.disabled." I know that's not quite what you're looking for, but it'd give you a simple, straightforward solution. Since you know the exact physical path, it should be easy to determine the current state and provide toggle capability based on the folder name. I've never gone this route; I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have hundreds of applications across dozens of websites.  Taking them all down to do the cleanup required is just not an option.  The goal is to have something coded to disable the applications that have reached their end of life.